# passing scope variables defined in http request from controller to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to pass the longitude and latitude from my get request in my controller to my directive. However, as the code currently stands, the scope variables when called in the directive are 'undefined'. If I 'console.log($scope.lat);' in my controller after the get request it is also 'undefined', so it seems as though the scope variables are not being passed outside the request. Does anyone know why this is? Thanks

```
angular.module('Ski').controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  'use strict';

  $http.get('https://quiet-journey-8066.herokuapp.com/mountains/5').success(function(response) {
      $scope.mountain = response.name;
      $scope.lat = response.latitude;
      $scope.lng = response.longitude;

    });

});



angular.module('Ski').directive('mapCanvas', function() {


  return {

    scope: {mapCanvas : '='},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.$parend.lat, scope.$parent.lng);      
      var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 14
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);


    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Way:

What we want to be able to do is separate the scope inside a directive from the scope outside, and then map the outer scope to a directive's inner scope.

See this example:

```
angular.module('Ski').directive('mapCanvas', function() {

  return {
    scope: {         
      lat: '=',
      lng: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var zoom = attrs.zoom || 14;

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.lat, scope.lng);

      var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: zoom
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);
    }
  };
});
```

And setup it like this:

```
<div map-canvas lat="lat" lng="lng" zoom="14">
  <!-- your content, zoom is optional-->
</div>
```

Where `lat` and `lng` are binded to the controller `$scope.lat` and `$scope.lng`

## Runnable Example with Map

Empiric

```js
angular.module('ski',[])
    
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {      
         $scope.lat = 40.71427;
         $scope.lng =  -74.00597;      
         $scope.extra = "New York City";
      
     })
    
    .directive('map', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          lat: '=',
          lng: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        template:'<div class="fullscreen"></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          
          var zoom = parseInt(attrs.zoom) || 14;
          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.lat, scope.lng);      
          var mapOptions = {
              center: myLatlng,
              zoom: zoom
          };

          var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);
          
        }
      };
    });
```

```css
html, body, .fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&extension=.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ski" ng-controller="ctrl" class="fullscreen">
<map lat="lat" lng="lng" zoom="12" ></map>
</div>
```

## Runnable Example without Map

Conceptual.

```js
angular.module('ski',[])
    
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
      
         $scope.lat = -32.634;
         $scope.lng = -54.534;      
         $scope.extra = "Angular Way";
      
     })
    
    .directive('mapCanvas', function() {
      return {
        // creates new isolated scope.
        scope: {
          lat: '=',
          lng: '='
        },
        // here lat, lng, other & extra refers to directive isolated scope, not controller scope.
        template: '<p> Lat: {{lat}} Lng: {{lng}} Other: {{other}} Extra: {{extra}}</p>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          // here scope means directive isolated scope.
          var zoom = attrs.zoom || 14;
          var extra = attrs.extra || "no extra";

          scope.other = zoom ;
          scope.extra = extra;
          
          console.log(scope.lat, scope.lng);
        }
      };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ski" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div map-canvas lat="lat" lng="lng" zoom="14" extra="{{extra}}">
  <!-- your content, zoom is optional-->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW: `While inspecting the html element` you should use [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) to inspect it, the browser *Inspect Element* option doesn't know about Angular internals